# Redirect output to websocket server

Tags: powershell, websocket, pipe

Is it possible to redirect the output of an executable to a websocket server using powershell? I tried using the Tee-Object but could only output to file or a variable.

So far I have the websocket and executable working separate, how do I pass the output to the websocket client?

```
$WS = New-Object System.Net.WebSockets.ClientWebSocket                                                
$CT = New-Object System.Threading.CancellationToken                                                   

$Conn = $WS.ConnectAsync("localhost:8080", $CT)                                                  
While (!$Conn.IsCompleted) { Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 100 }


#How do I continue here?

$WS.SendAsync(...)
myprocess.exe | Tee -Variable ...
```

Comment: Can you share the code you tried? Is the problem to catch std output from the executable?

Comment: @MikeTwc, I updated the question with my code snippet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume myprocess.exe is generating messages you want to send over WS. To catch and send those messages you can use foreach:

```
myprocess.exe | foreach { $WS.SendAsync($_) }
```

You may also create your own cmdlet that will accept input from pipeline

```
function Send-WS { begin { ...define $WS} process { $WS.Send } End { ..do smth at the end} }
myprocess.exe | Send-WS
```

Comment: Perfect, Thanks!

Comment: Wouldn't that wait for the process to complete first, accumulating all messages somewhere, before Powershell splitting them into lines which is what `foreach`  is invoked on then?